# Bridge between phpbb and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phpbb

I want to create an authentication bridge between phpbb and wordpress. I know they cant share the same database but is there a way to make a single sign-on for them?

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/phpbb-single-sign-on/ ?

Comment: actually that plugin is a little buggy. I wondered if there was anything other than that?